# Can I sell a futuristic patent company

Tags: licensing, business-methods, science-fiction, futurism

Would it be possible to sell I futuristic space Mineing patents to a company’s using a patent examples a super intelligent system patents to a company or in immortality and lots of other things that are in sci-fi fantasy and could I give my patant license to them to company’s to research and development no matter how crazy ideas is or futuristic

Comment: Have you actually invented these things and are planning on filing patents ? To file a patent you need to know how it will work.

Comment: I'm assuming English is not your primary language. This is okay, but I'm afraid it's not quite clear what you are asking. I'm willing to help edit for grammatical correctness if you could perhaps review and clarify the question.

Comment: Without a comment or edit from the OP this question may be closed as vague and therefore unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Patents are not granted for ideas, only implementations. Star Trek described the transporter beam and warp drive, but without a working implementation, those are just ideas and not patentable. A good example of a futuristic idea that did result in a patent is the [solar power satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power) which was described as a work of science fiction in 1941 by Isaac Asimov. [Peter Glaser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Glaser) obtained a [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3781647A/en?oq=us3%2C781%2C647) for a solar power satellite in 1973. Evidently the USPTO felt his description of how to implement such a device was sufficient to grant the patent.

The patent expired in 1990 so I seriously doubt Dr. Glaser earned any licensing income from it. This is probably the biggest block to getting income from futuristic ideas. Even if you do manage to obtain a patent, the technology needs to be economically viable before the patent expires or else no one would have any reason to license it.